# Issues with calling json file using powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to run simple power-shell command to call json file to deploy some resources on Azure but it give me the same errors each time I try to run the file.The error message I am getting is -

```
New-AzDeployment : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Invalid property identifier character: �. Path '', line 2, position 0.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzDeployment -Name $DeploymentName -Location uksouth -TemplateUri ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzDeployment], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureDeploymentCmdlet
```

below is the powershell, I am trying to run -

```
$DeploymentSubscription = "Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN"
$DeploymentRSG = "xyz"
$DeploymentName = "vvv"
$ParameterRoute = "D:\xyz\json\VM\"
$ParameterFile = $ParameterRoute + "Build.json"
$TemplateFileRoute = "D:\xyz\VM\"
$TemplateFileName = "Deploy_RG_Resources.json"
$TemplateFile = $TemplateFileRoute + $TemplateFileName
$TemplateFileURi = $TemplateFileRoute + $TemplateFileName

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name $DeploymentName -ResourceGroupName $DeploymentRSG -DeploymentDebugLogLevel All -Verbose -TemplateUri $TemplateFileURi -TemplateParameterFile $ParameterFile
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is resolved now .Issue was with the JSON template syntax.Quite weird though I have validate the template many times

Answer (score 0):

That error is very specific.
What you are passing is valid. The help files for the cmdlet shows this command in action.

[New-Az​Resource​Group​Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-2.0.0)

```
$newAzResourceGroupDeploymentSplat = @{
    TemplateParameterFile = "D:\Azure\Templates\EngSiteParams.json"
    TemplateObject = $TemplateObject
    ResourceGroupName = "ContosoEngineering"
}
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @newAzResourceGroupDeploymentSplat
```

Note the fully qualified UNC to the .json file.

But you are doing this..

```
$ParameterFile = $ParameterRoute + "Build.json"
```

...  and based on your post, that is not the path to your .json file.

Comment: I have tried with the Json file locally as well the error is the same.[$ParameterFile = $ParameterRoute + "Build.json"] - It contains local file path + the file name .If I use the remote file I receive the same error I have validate the Json files as well can't think of anything else.

Comment: this is resolved now .Issue was with the JSON template syntax.Quite weird though I have validate the template many times

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-TemplateFile` as parameter instead of `-TemplateUri` if your Template file in on local machine.

Comment: I have tried the -TemplateFile as well and the error message is the same